# How to ouput in HTML TABLE a "SELECT STATEMENT" in Groups

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, reporting

I have tables joined {Project, Task, expense}
Project has a project name, and task has Job Type, then expense has the detailed information I needed.

```
project.project id = task.project_id

expense.task_id = task.task_id
```

so what I wanted to do is show it in groups

[image]

I have made several reports listing but I have not grouped them like this. I made this image easy by using a Reporting Tools in PowerBuilder(like Visual Basic). But I am not familiar if there is something I can use like those using PHP/MySQL. I use CodeIgniter by the way...

Comment: Please show all of your HTML markup, CSS and table schema if you would like some help. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I still dont have them yet. I only use the CodeIngiter Report to CSV. I just wanted to know if its possible to do the report like the image I posted. Currently it is show like this, for the dog, food for the dog, pedigree, 25

Comment: Anything is possible if you have the knowledge and experience.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you enlighten me somehow on where to start.

Comment: Using MySQL/PHP/CodeIgniter Framework

Comment: Well.. i did it by retrieving data threetimes instead of 1 view and series of for loops. thanks

Comment: i still would like a better way. i am still having trouble passing the third table to array and recognizing it...